# Javascript code inside function not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fire the img.onerror event but can't seem to figure out why the last line of my code is not running. When I start the debugger it gets to the line where the error event is bound to the image but then it never gets to the line with this.src.

```
$("img").each(function () {

    this.error(function () {
        alert("error!");
    })

    this.src = "data:image;base64,invalidDatalFTkSuQmCC";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RK6G9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `each` callback function `this` is a reference to the `img` DOM node (`HTMLImageElement`). It is *not* a jQuery collection. Using, `$(this).error(...)` should fix the issue.

As it appears that you're binding a similar callback to each `error` event, and setting the same `src` property, you could simplify your code to:

```
$('img').error(function () {
    alert('error');
}).prop('src', 'data:image;base64,invalidDatalFTkSuQmCC');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap `this` to make it a jQuery object:

```
$(this).error....
```

The console is also your friend, you'll see with your current code you get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'error'
```

Comment: Cool, got it working. Was confused as the first 'this' needed to be a jquery object and the second this a regular js object (not wrapped in $(this):
http://jsfiddle.net/RK6G9/2/